# Term for using immigrants to gain long term political advantage

Tags: united-states, election, democracy, terminology

Is there a term that defines the process of a political party or system bringing in immigrants (legal/illegal/refugees) to make them citizens in the future with the expectation that they will support that party or system?

I am looking for a term equivalent to *gerrymandering* if such a term exists.

Answer (score 1):

Population Transfer, demographic displacement, let's look at what the UN has to say..

> Indigenous peoples have the collective and individual right not to be
> subjected to ethnocide and cultural genocide, including prevention of
> and redress for:
>
> (a) Any action which has the aim or effect of depriving them of their integrity as distinct peoples, or of their cultural values or ethnic identities;
> (b) Any action which has the aim or effect of dispossessing them of their lands, territories or resources;
> (c) Any form of population transfer which has the aim or effect of violating or undermining any of their rights;
> (d) Any form of assimilation or integration by other cultures or ways of life imposed on them by legislative, administrative or other measures;
> (e) Any form of propaganda directed against them.